# What are the Chances of getting a map/set iterator not dereferencable with boost serialization

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I keep on getting a `map/set iterator not dereferencable` assertion in my program. I am totally confused as I am having difficulty understanding why this is occuring. While glimpsing over the stack trace which is given below.

```
    msvcp100d.dll!std::_Debug_message()  + 0x23 bytes   
    msvcp100d.dll!std::_Debug_message()  + 0x16 bytes   
>   PROG.exe!std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tmap_traits<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> >,0> > >::operator*()  Line 236 + 0x15 bytes    C++
    PROG.exe!boost::serialization::stl::save_collection<boost::archive::text_oarchive,std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > >(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, const std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > & s)  Line 63 + 0x11 bytes  C++
    PROG.exe!boost::serialization::save<boost::archive::text_oarchive,SomeClass,int,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > >(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, const std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > & t, const unsigned int __formal)  Line 41 + 0xd bytes C++
    PROG.exe!boost::serialization::free_saver<boost::archive::text_oarchive,std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > >::invoke(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, const std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > & t, const unsigned int file_version)  Line 45 + 0x18 bytes   C++
    PROG.exe!boost::serialization::split_free<boost::archive::text_oarchive,std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > >(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > & t, const unsigned int file_version)  Line 74 + 0x11 bytes C++
    PROG.exe!boost::serialization::serialize<boost::archive::text_oarchive,SomeClass,int,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > >(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > & t, const unsigned int file_version)  Line 70 + 0x11 bytes C++
    PROG.exe!boost::serialization::serialize_adl<boost::archive::text_oarchive,std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > >(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > & t, const unsigned int file_version)  Line 128 + 0x18 bytes C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive,std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > >::save_object_data(boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive & ar, const void * x)  Line 152 + 0x31 bytes C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive_impl::save_object(boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive & ar, const void * t, const boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer & bos)  Line 275 C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::save_object(const void * x, const boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer & bos)  Line 424   C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save_standard::invoke<std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > >(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, const std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > & t)  Line 259   C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::invoke<std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > >(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, const std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > & t)  Line 308 + 0xd bytes  C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::save<boost::archive::text_oarchive,std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > const >(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, const std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > & t)  Line 525 + 0xd bytes  C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save_override<std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > const >(const std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > & t, int __formal)  Line 69 + 0x15 bytes C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save_override<std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > const >(const std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > & t, int __formal)  Line 81  C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::operator<<<std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > const >(const std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > & t)  Line 64    C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::operator&<std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > >(std::map<int,SomeClass,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,SomeClass> > > & t)  Line 75 C++
    PROG.exe!---::serialize<boost::archive::text_oarchive>(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, const unsigned int version)  Line 42 C++
    PROG.exe!boost::serialization::access::serialize<boost::archive::text_oarchive,--->(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, --- & t, const unsigned int file_version)  Line 119 C++
    PROG.exe!boost::serialization::serialize<boost::archive::text_oarchive,--->(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, --- & t, const unsigned int file_version)  Line 69 + 0x11 bytes C++
    PROG.exe!boost::serialization::serialize_adl<boost::archive::text_oarchive,--->(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, --- & t, const unsigned int file_version)  Line 128 + 0x18 bytes    C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive,--->::save_object_data(boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive & ar, const void * x)  Line 152 + 0x31 bytes   C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive_impl::save_object(boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive & ar, const void * t, const boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer & bos)  Line 275 C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::save_object(const void * x, const boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer & bos)  Line 424   C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save_standard::invoke<--->(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, const --- & t)  Line 259  C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::invoke<--->(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, const --- & t)  Line 308 + 0xd bytes C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::invoke<--->(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, --- & t)  Line 314 + 0xd bytes   C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::save<boost::archive::text_oarchive,--->(boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, --- & t)  Line 525 + 0xd bytes C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save_override<--->(--- & t, int __formal)  Line 69 + 0x15 bytes    C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save_override<--->(--- & t, int __formal)  Line 81 C++
    PROG.exe!boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::operator<<<--->(--- & t)  Line 64   C++
    PROG.exe!DipqCon::Dispatach_Ecl(--- & hf, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & symbol)  Line 123  C++
```

I am suspicious that this may be caused due to boost serialization.
I am serializing as follows:

```
void DipqCon::Dispatach_Ecl(SomeObject &hf)
{
   std::stringstream ss; 
   boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss); 
   oa << hf;
   std::string serialized = ss.str();
   DoSomething(serialized);
}
```

I wanted to know what the chances of getting (if any of getting a map/set iterator not dereferencable) assertion here.

Comment: If your program does not have Undefined Behavior, the chances are near zero.  If your program has Undefined Behavior, nothing can be calculated about it.  Is your question really about probabilities?

Comment: My question is are there any chances of getting this error while serializing. Does boost use any unordered structure during serialization